# nonlinear to linear separable map dimension

Tags: data-transformation

Does it need to always the dimention of a destination space($N'$) of transformation for particular data set($D$) that is not linearly separable in origin space($R^N$) be equal or greater($N \le N'$) than origin space($R^N$) ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a data set that resides in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that if its distance from the origin is more than  $1$, it belongs to the positive data class and if the distance from the origin is less than $1$, it belongs to the negative class.

Such data is not linearly separable.

We can define the destination space to be the distance from the origin, hence mapping to $\mathbb{R}$ suffices.

Comment: i suggest one more than 1 and one less than one,what you are saing is true so why in classification we always search for space for greater dimension?

Comment: We don't always go to higher dimensional space. As discussed in this [quora](https://www.quora.com/Support-Vector-Machines-How-does-going-to-higher-dimension-help-data-get-linearly-separable-which-was-non-linearly-separable-in-actual-dimension) link by Andrea Baisero.